.Net Aspire with Entra ID Signout not working
I'm having trouble logging out from Entra ID & stuck as logged in user. Below is the link in my NavMenu.razor which I'm calling directly
   <AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
            <a href="signout-callback-oidc" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Logout</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="signin-oidc" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Login</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


The appsettings is
"AzureAd": {
  "Authority": "https://guestxcustomers.ciamlogin.com/",
  "ClientId": "id",
  "ClientCredentials": [
    {
      "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
      "ClientSecret": "secret"
    }
  ],
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}

In program.cs I have added that on Home page it should redirect if user is trying to see the page with "Authorize"
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

Any help will be appreciated as I'm new to this. Thanks!
I have tried calling it, also by hardcoding it but nothing works. I have checked the authentication as well in Entra website, the url for logout there is "https://localhost:7081/signout-callback-oidc"

Hi, what arr the logs of the app saying?????
